# How to change elements of a pointer to a vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

Let's say I have a couple of vectors of integers and a pointer to a vector of integers. How would I go about changing the value of one element of the pointer to be the address in one of the other vectors of integers?

The context for this is that I've built a class that lets me bring in my desktop into the unreal engine, however on each tick it has to assign a form of vector that contains a struct to the values of another data class each tick, I instead wish to copy the memory addresses over for only a few of the elements (the pixel colour values) so I don't waste time by having to do a copy twice (which for a desktop image is millions of operations)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Print function
void PrintVector(vector<int> v)
{
 for( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
 {
 cout << v[i] << ", ";
 }
 cout << endl;
}

int main()
{

    vector<int> vector1;
    vector<int> vector2;
    vector<int> *ptrvector;

    //Do some assignment so the vectors have values
    for( int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        vector1.push_back(i);
        vector2.push_back(2*i);
    }
    //Assign the pointer to the address of vector1.
    ptrvector = &vector1;

    //Print out:
    PrintVector(vector1);  // (1,2,3)
    PrintVector(vector2);  // (2,4,6)
    PrintVector(*ptrvector); // (1,2,3)
    // We should see that lines 1 and 3 are the same

    //BROKEN BIT::

    //Ideally want something like
    ptrvector[0] = &vector2[2];
    PrintVector(*ptrvector); // (6,2,3);

    //Such that if I were to do this:
    vector2[2] = 20;
    PrintVector(*ptrvector); // It should change as a side effect: (20,2,3)


}
```

BONUS QUESTION:

Let's say I have this:

```
TArray<FColor> ColorData;
TArray<FColor> *ptrColorData
//Where TArray is essentially a vector. FColor is a struct with members (R,G,B,A)

//ColorData is initialised somewhere and we set the ptrColorData to the address
ptrColorData = &ColorData;

//Somewhere down the line we have a long loop whereby we do
ColorData[i].B = somedata[i];
ColorData[i].G = somedata[i+1];
ColorData[i].R = somedata[i+3];

//somedata is updated per tick, asigning ColorData per tick as well slows it down.
// I wish to be able to do something on the lines of this

ptrColorData[i].B = &somedata[i];
ptrColorData[i].G = &somedata[i+1];
ptrColorData[i].R = &somedata[i+3];

// this is only called once to initialize. Because the memory address
//is unchanging and somedata changes by functions on its own it means when
// I tell my unreal engine to update a texture by passing (*ptrColorData)
// to a function it automatically has the new data when that function is
// next called.
```

Comment: To address elements in a `std::vector` by pointer is not impossible but I wouldn't recommend to do so. Please, be aware that as soon as you add elements to a vector it might re-allocate its internal storage. Hence, all pointers would become broken (dangling). Better is to address elements in a vector by index.

Comment: If you insist to address vector elements by pointers... You can get the address of a vector element simply by using the address operator (`operator&()`) as usual. E.g. `std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; int *pA = &vec[2]; // pA points to vec[2] now.`

Comment: May be, I got your intention wrong. `ptrvector[0] = &vector2[2];` This would work with the the correct indirection: `(*ptrvector)[0] = vector2[2];` Please, be aware a pointer to vector is not a vector of pointers. I believe you have confused this...

Comment: @Scheff Thank you! I wasn't quite aware of the correct notation for the pointers. This correctly updates the pointer's address, however if I were to say assign `vector2[2] = someothernumber` the address of `vector2[2]` changes which is what I'm trying to avoid. Might be thinking of something impossible here ( I don't know the full details in how it allocates memory ) but the intention was that if the memory address was unchanging I could shave off a few million operations as my set-up pointer to a vector would have its values at the addresses update without having to do an additional copy.

Comment: "however if I were to say assign `vector2[2] = someothernumber` the address of `vector2[2]` changes" - no, it does not change its address

Comment: @Fureeish my mistake, I was trying to check why updating vector[2] wasn't updating *ptrvector and was checking the memory addresses of each vector, turns out I had a typo with it, though the problem here I think is by using (*ptrvector)[0] all I'm doing is assigning what ptrvector is pointing to at it's 0th entry (the value) and not the memory address itself so updating fails.

Answer (score 2):

This should produce the output you want, but be aware. As stated in the comments, the addresses stored int the `std::vector<int*>` should be considered invalid if you change the size of `vector1` or `vector2` in any way and if you reorder the elements in the original vectors, your pointers will point to the wrong values. I also removed `using namespace std;`. See: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Print function
void PrintVector(std::vector<int> v) {
    for(auto x : v) std::cout << x << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void PrintVector(std::vector<int*> v) {
    for(auto x : v) std::cout << *x << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vector1;
    std::vector<int> vector2;
    std::vector<int*> ptrvector; // pointers to the elements in vector1/2

    //Do some assignment so the vectors have values
    for( int i = 1; i<=3; i++) {
        vector1.push_back(i);
        vector2.push_back(2*i);
    }
    // Add pointers in ptrvector to the addresses in vector1.
    ptrvector.reserve(vector1.size());
    for(auto& r : vector1)
        ptrvector.emplace_back(&r);

    //Print out:
    PrintVector(vector1);   // (1,2,3)
    PrintVector(vector2);   // (2,4,6)
    PrintVector(ptrvector); // (1,2,3)

    ptrvector[0] = &vector2[2];
    PrintVector(ptrvector); // (6,2,3);

    vector2[2] = 20;
    PrintVector(ptrvector); // (20,2,3)
}
```